# Firemonkey (Rad Studio 10.3.2) current time issue on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, firemonkey-fm3, current-time

If there any solution how to fix mediaplayer. Currenttime on Android (Rad studio 10.3.2) ? Values not correct (sometimes negative values), on windows work fine

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I modified the following code in FMX.Media.Android.pas to fix it.  It seems Embarcadero hasn't bothered fixing it for several versions.

`Result := Round(TMediaTime(FPlayer.getCurrentPosition) * MediaTimeScale / MSecsPerSec);`